# How to plot grid plots on a same page?

Tags: r, plot, treemap, r-grid

I am using a package (`treemap`) that uses `grid` package to produce a treemap. However, I would like to plot several of these treemaps together, to add [different color schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223520/treemap-package-in-r-use-different-palettes-for-first-index-parameter-and-shade) to these plots. `tmPlot` function uses `grid.newpage` function, which clears the graphics window. I have not found a way to save `grid.newpage` objects as you can do for `ggplot2`objects. Is there a way to plot several `grid.newpage` objects to a same window?

```
## Example

library(treemap)

# load Gross national income data
data(GNI2010)

size <- aggregate(GNI ~ continent, GNI2010, sum)
size <- size[with(size, order(GNI, decreasing = T)),]

cont <- size$continent

widths <- c(sum(size[c(1,3,5),]$GNI),
sum(size$GNI) - sum(size[c(1,3,5),]$GNI))

heights <- c(sum(size[c(1,2),]$GNI),
sum(size[c(3,4),]$GNI),
sum(size[c(5,6),]$GNI))

palettes <- c("Greens", "Blues", "Reds", "Oranges", "Purples", "Greys")

i <- 1 # This is to be replaced by for loop

x <- subset(GNI2010, continent == cont[i], cex = 5)

# create treemap

layout(matrix(1:6, 3, byrow = TRUE), widths = widths, heights = heights)
x1 <- tmPlot(x,
index=c("iso3"),
vSize="population",
vColor="GNI",
type="value", title = "", 
position.legend = "none",
palette = palettes[i])
grid.text(cont[i], 0.5, 0.5, gp=gpar(fontsize=20, font = 2, col = "white"))

## x1 is does not make a plot as such and tmPlot overwrites layout
```

I understand that my solution to scale the plots based on GNI sum is not right. I might make another question about that later, once I figure out how to plot these treemaps in a same window.

**EDIT:** I think the answer to this question is "**no**". Currently you cannot save grid.newpage objects by name, neither can you save several of these on a page, because the function "erases the current device or moves to a new page" as said in the [description](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/grid.newpage.html). However, it is possible to find work arounds. `tmPlot` package does not currently (as of 23 March, 2013) support `viewport`s, but the development version does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your question. The output of tmPlot is indeed not a saved plot.

In the next update I will add argument vp, by which a viewport can be specified to draw in. Only if it is not specified, grid.newpage is called.

UPDATE: You could check and test the development version at https://github.com/mtennekes/treemap

To apply the example of Bryan Hanson:

```
vplayout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))
tmPlot(GNI2010,
  index="continent",
  vSize="population",
  vColor="GNI",
  type="value",
  vp = vplayout(1,1))
tmPlot(GNI2010,
  index=c("continent", "iso3"),
  vSize="population",
  vColor="GNI",
  type="value",
  vp = vplayout(1,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that is very flexible for any grid graphics:

```
vplayout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))
print(a, vp = vplayout(1,1))
print(b, vp = vplayout(1,2))
```

Where `a` and `b` are your saved plot objects.  So test each plot individually ahead of time, save them as `a, b, ...` then plot them as above.

Oh, and if `tmPlot` always does `grid.newpage` then check to see if it has a has `new.page` argument which you can set to `FALSE`, or make a copy of the function and comment out the `newpage`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The trouble is that I don't know how to save the tmPlots as objects. I am aware of the line you sent, and it works very well for ggplot2 objects.

Comment: Where did you get `treeplot`?  It's not on CRAN and there's a slew of things with that name if one googles.

Comment: Ops...I meant: `treemap`. Sorry for the mistake. I edited my question.

Comment: Bad news: `?tmPlot` says it returns a list, not a grid graphics object.  I created one, and it looks like it is intended to be plotted by the internal routines.  However, these internal routines are hidden from the user.  These things can be found and hacked but it might be easier to contact the package maintainer and see if they have a quick solution.

Comment: Do `getAnywhere("baseTreemap")` and you'll see the function that actually does the plotting.  The way it is structured it will be very difficult to capture what you want.  How about a different approach: loop over your viewports and use `tmPlot` at each point rather than creating all the plots in advance.

Comment: Yep, I looked at the code too. I was just hoping that there would be `grid.plot` command or similar thing that would plot anything on `grid.newpage`. One option would be to save the plots as files and plot them as raster images. Pity that `grob` does not support vector graphics, right?

Comment: "How about a different approach: loop over your viewports and use tmPlot at each point rather than creating all the plots in advance." tmPlot overwrites the graphic window, so at least I did not manage in that. Maybe I did something wrong.

Comment: Maybe check out this: journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-1/RJournal_2011-1_Murrell.pdf

Comment: @`Bryan Hanson` Thanks! Another approach would be to save `tmPlot`s as pdfs and use the width/height arguments to scale the size of the plot file. Then it would be rather easy to combine these plots using Illustrator, yet preserving vector format. I think I might do that unless someone comes with a magical solution.

Comment: you can always capture the drawing into a grob with `grid.grabExpr` and draw that in a specific viewport.