# Multiple R treemaps on a single page with scaling

Tags: r, treemap

I'm trying to put multiple treemaps on a single page.  Each tree map is for a subset of the data and it would be useful to see them all at once.  The following code creates a treemap for each subset but they each are on their own page.

Question 1) Is there a way to put all of the treemaps on one page?
Question 2) Is there a way to scale the overall size each treemap making some larger and some smaller?

```
library(treemap)
library(plyr)

numSubsets = sapply(df[myIndexColumn], function(x) length(unique(x)))
par(mfrow=c(1, numSubsets))
do_treemap <- function(mySubset)
{

  t <- paste("Subset Number",mySubset$subset_num[1])
  treemap(mySubset, index=c("Level 1","Level 2"), vSize="sizeVar", vColor="colorVar", title=t)
}

ddply(df, .variables=c("subset_num"), .fun=do_treemap)
```

Comment: This topic is discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000525/how-to-plot-grid-plots-on-a-same-page/15001309#15001309 But another problem is when you use `mfrow` you are using `base` graphics and `treemap` uses `grid` graphics, and the two are generally not compatible.

Answer (score 2):

the treemap function accepts a "vp" argument which is a grid viewport.

```
grid.newpage()
grid.rect()
pushViewport(viewport(layout=grid.layout(3, 1)))


do_treemap <- function(ind){
    vp <- viewport(layout.pos.col=1, layout.pos.row=ind)
    pushViewport(vp)
    treemap(business, index=c("NACE1", "NACE2", "NACE3"), vSize="turnover", type="index",vp=vp)
    popViewport()
    popViewport() #treemap doees not seem to pop corretly
    popViewport() #and one more!
}

lapply(1:3, do_treemap)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question, and Ido, thanks for your correct answer.

There was indeed a small bug that required two additional popViewports. Apart from that, you don't need to push vp (and pop it afterwards). The bug is fixed in the current github version.

```
require(grid)
grid.newpage()

data(business)
numVars <- c("turnover", "turnover.prev", "employees", "employees.prev")

pushViewport(viewport(layout=grid.layout(length(numVars), 1)))
do_treemap <- function(ind){
    vp <- viewport(layout.pos.col=1, layout.pos.row=ind)
    treemap(business, index=c("NACE1", "NACE2"), vSize=numVars[ind],
    type="index",vp=vp) 
    upViewport(2) # Needed in version 2.0.1 due to bug. Not needed in later versions (i.e. github)
}

lapply(seq_along(numVars), do_treemap)
```

UPDATE: to come back to your second question: the sizes of the subplots are controlled by the viewport. For example:

```
require(grid)
grid.newpage()

data(business)
numVars <- c("turnover", "turnover.prev", "employees", "employees.prev")

pushViewport(viewport(layout=grid.layout(2, 2, widths=c(0.4,0.6), heights=c(0.7,0.3))))

for (i in 1:2) {
     for (j in 1:2) {
         vp <- viewport(layout.pos.col=i, layout.pos.row=j)
         treemap(business, index=c("NACE1", "NACE2"), vSize=numVars[i+(j-1)*2],
                 type="index",vp=vp)
         upViewport(2) # Needed in version 2.0.1 due to bug. Not needed in later versions (i.e. github)
     }
}
```

In addition, you can specify the treemap argument aspRatio to control the ratio between width and height.