# combining multiple treemap wtih grid.arrange

Tags: r, treemap, gridextra

I would like to use the treemap package in combination with grid.arrange. Assigning a treemap to a value in the “regular” way does not seem to work

```
library(treemap) 
library(gridExtra) 
data(business)

P1 <- treemap(business,
index=c("NACE1", "NACE2", "NACE3"),
vSize="turnover
type="index")
```

Any tricks how I could use it? Or any other way how I could arrange two plots in one graph? 
My plan was something like

```
P2 <- treemap(business,
index=c("NACE1", "NACE2", "NACE3"),
vSize="turnover",
type="index")

grid.arrange(P1,P2)
```

I use version 2.4 with treemap and version 2.2.1 with gridExtra

Thank you Hanna

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. For this you need to add sample data and all libraries you loaded.

Comment: the last line does not work, as it is exactly my problem, thanx

library(treemap)
library(gridExtra)
data(business)

p1<-treemap(business,
        index=c("NACE1", "NACE2", "NACE3"),
        vSize="turnover",
        type="index")

p2<-treemap(business,
            index=c("NACE1", "NACE2", "NACE3"),
            vSize="turnover",
            type="index")
grid.arrange(p1,p2)

Comment: I stumbled over the answer, this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400771/multiple-r-treemaps-on-a-single-page-with-scaling