# How to put two 'vcd' grid graphics in a single plot?

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization, r-grid

I would like to place two (somewhat non-standard) grid graphics in a single plot in R.

Try:

```
require(vcd)
mosaic(Titanic)
assoc(Titanic)
```

The trouble is that these aren't `lattice` graphics, and to my knowledge do not come with a `layout` argument or similar. And since these are `grid` graphs, they're impervious to `base` graph tricks like `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`.

How can I place the two graphs above in a single plot, with both graphs on the same line?

I already tried the suggestions in [How to plot grid plots on a same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000525/how-to-plot-grid-plots-on-a-same-page), but they don't seem to work for `vcd` plots. Ultimately I would like to obtain something similar to:

[image]

Comment: Neither plot seems to return any object ... and i cant see how to grab the grobs from looking at `grid.ls()` . You can abuse the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929452/r-return-corrplot-as-object/27948707#27948707) ... `mosaic(Titanic) ; m <- grid.grab() ; assoc(Titanic) ; a <- grid.grab(); grid.newpage() ;grid.arrange(m, a, ncol=2)`

Comment: @user20650: You should post as an answer.

Comment: thanks @BondedDust; i was expecting there to be a more succinct approach ... but perhaps this is a quick means to an end

Comment: you can pass a `return_grob = TRUE` argument to mosaicplot, but that seems to use grid.grab anyway.

Comment: @baptiste Could you post this approach as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Neither plot seems to return any object and I cant see how to grab the grobs from looking at `grid.ls()`. So using the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929452/r-return-corrplot-as-object/27948707#27948707)

```
library(vcd) 
library(gridGraphics)
library(gridExtra)

mosaic(Titanic)  
m <- grid.grab()  

assoc(Titanic)  
a <- grid.grab()

grid.newpage()
grid.arrange(m, a, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Im sure there will be a more *grid-like* approach but ...

Comment: I'm not sure about a more grid like approach being feasible. Neither of those functions returns a grid object, although there is a newpage=FALSE option to suppress one of the hindrances to using them as grid functions. Furthermore I was failing in my efforts so I thought you ought to step up and claim credit.

Comment: Thanks! This does what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

Something similar to the solution in [How to plot grid plots on a same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15000525/how-to-plot-grid-plots-on-a-same-page) can also be used for `vcd` displays. The difference is that you need to set `newpage = FALSE` (to prevent opening a new display) and you need to push and pop the viewport yourself (which can be handy when re-using `vcd` graphics in more complicated displays such as `partykit` trees).

The mosaic and association display for the `Titanic` data can be visualized as:

```
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))

pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 1, layout.pos.row = 1))
mosaic(Titanic, newpage = FALSE)
popViewport()

pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.row = 1, layout.pos.col = 2))
assoc(Titanic, newpage = FALSE)
popViewport()
```

yielding

[image: Mosaic and association display]

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `vcd`’s `mplot()` function (for details, see `?vcd::mplot`):

```
library(vcd)
mplot(
  mosaic(Titanic, return_grob = TRUE),
  assoc(Titanic, return_grob = TRUE),
  keep_aspect_ratio = FALSE
)
```

[image: output]